# Using awk to print a new column without apostrophes or spaces

Tags: bash, awk

I'm processing a text file and adding a column composed of certain components of other columns. A new requirement to remove spaces and apostrophes was requested and I'm not sure the most efficient way to accomplish this task.

The file's content can be created by the following script:

```
content=(
  john    smith          thomas       blank    123    123456    10  
  jane    smith          elizabeth    blank    456    456123    12  
  erin    "o'brien"      margaret     blank    789    789123    9  
  juan    "de la cruz"   carlos       blank    1011   378943    4
)
# put this into a tab-separated file, with the syntactic (double) quotes above removed
printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' "${content[@]}" >infile
```

This is what I have now, but it fails to remove spaces and apostrophes:

```
awk -F "\t" '{OFS="\t"; print $1,$2,$3,$5,$6,$7,$6 tolower(substr($2,0,3)); }' infile > outfile
```

This throws an error "sub third parameter is not a changeable object", which makes sense since I'm trying to process output instead of input, I guess.

```
awk -F "\t" '{OFS="\t"; print $1,$2,$3,$5,$6,$7,$6 sub("'\''", "",tolower(substr($2,0,3))); }' infile > outfile
```

Is there a way I can print a combination of column 6 and part of column 2 in lower case, all while removing spaces and apostrophes from the output to the new column?  Worst case scenario, I can just create a new file with my first command and process that output with a new awk command, but I'd like to do it in one pass is possible.

Comment: Is there a reason you want `awk` for this, instead of using (say) bash built-in functionality?

Comment: It'd also be helpful to provide a standalone example that doesn't require someone to provide their own `infile` to test.

Comment: I don't have awk as a requirement, but it seemed like a logical solution given I'm processing a file with tab separated content and I don't wish to apply changes to all columns. If you have another solution that doesn't use awk, I'm definitely open to other options.

Comment: Please [edit] to provide input and desired output -- otherwise, folks with possible solutions can't test them. That might be just a command that generates the input, something like: `{ printf '%s\t' foo bar "two words" "'five words enclosed in quotes'" baz; printf '\n'; } | awk ...`; see also the docs on building a [mcve].

Comment: That said, in bash, `while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a words; do ...` will loop over a stream of input, putting each piece into an element of the array `words`; `${foo//[[:space:]\']}` will evaluate to a version of `foo` with spaces and apostrophes removed... that's the big pieces of what you need to do this without awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach was close, but for order of operations:

```
awk -F "\t" '
  BEGIN { OFS="\t"; }
  {
    var=$2;
    sub("['\''[:space:]]", "", var);
    var=substr(var, 0, 3);
    print $1,$2,$3,$5,$6,$7,$6 var;
  }
'
```

- Assigning the contents you want to modify to a variable lets that variable be modified in-place.
- Characters you want to remove should be removed **before** taking the substring, since otherwise you shorten your 3-character substring.

Comment: You forgot to take care of the double quote, so it prints 789123"ob, which should be 789123obr.

Comment: @mlambrichs, ...this code absolutely does print `78123obr` given your provided input, because the only quote in that input is single, not double. You specified only "apostrophes" -- those are single quotes. So, no, I didn't forget anything.

Comment: You're barking at the wrong tree. ;-) I just checked your solution, that's all. And I checked it with the input of an earlier version of OP. My bad.

Comment: @mlambrichs, ...oh, right -- that wasn't you; sorry 'bout that. (Looking at the question's history, I don't see any version of the question that had `o"brien` -- perhaps the OP used similar data on a prior question earlier?)

Comment: No. Just checked. Had a "o'brien" that was tripping me up.

Comment: Oh, gotcha -- so using the script text from the question (including syntactic, vs literal, double quotes) as data, not the output file that script creates (with only the literal quotes, and the syntactic ones removed).

Answer (score 0):

It's a guess since you didn't provide the expected output but is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    abbr = $2
    gsub(/[\047[:space:]]/,"",abbr)
    abbr = tolower(substr(abbr,1,3))
    print $1,$2,$3,$5,$6,$7,$6 abbr
}

$ awk -f tst.awk infile
john    smith   thomas  123     123456  10      123456smi
jane    smith   elizabeth       456     456123  12      456123smi
erin    o'brien margaret        789     789123  9       789123obr
juan    de la cruz      carlos  1011    378943  4       378943del
```

Note that the way to represent a `'` in a `'`-enclosed awk script is with the octal `\047` (which will continue to work if/when you move your script to a file, unlike if you relied on `"'\''"` which only works from the command line), and that strings, arrays, and fields in awk start at 1, not 0, so your `substr(..,0,3)` is wrong and awk is treating the invalid start position of `0` as if you had used the first valid start position which is `1`.

The `"sub third parameter is not a changeable object"` error you were getting is because `sub()` modifies the object you call it with as the 3rd argument but you're calling it with a literal string (the output of `tolower(substr(...))`) and you can't modify a literal string - try `sub(/o/,"","foo")` and you'll get the same error vs if you used `var="foo"; sub(/o/,"",var)` which is valid since you can modify the content of variables.

Comment: A difference between the output of our two answers -- mine emits `789123obr`, not `789123ob`

Comment: Right, because you're removing the `'` before the substr() call and I'm doing it afterwards. I'm just following what the OP had in his code (removing the `'` after the substr() call) - since he didn't post the expected output idk which is correct.

Comment: Right. I'd be very surprised if the OP *wanted* less than a three-character substring in output.

Comment: I decided you're probably right and the OP really does want to remove the spaces and apostrophes first so I updated my answer.